# Keycloak reducer for JS giving error "Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches"

Tags: redux, keycloak

I am getting this error when I am trying to set the store.getState().keycloak = kc. It calls this reducer.

```
export default function keycloakReducer(keycloak = {}, action) {

 let nCloak = keycloak;

 return nCloak;
}
```

Any idea on how I can change up this reducer to not cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the call to the reducer to

store.dispatch({type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, keycloak: kc});